# Is there a way to make a continuous population density map?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, intuition

I have only ever seen population density maps divided into discrete sections (for example, [counties](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/50631261e4b0e9530e2c53a7/1498106903979-0LLXG4RPPV0QJZBNI6YG/UsaPopulationDensity2000.jpg)), but never one that assigns some continuous density value to each spot on the map. I see why it is difficult (or maybe impossible) to do this, as if the area of each of the regions approached zero, then we would just end up with 350 million discrete points on the map.

Speaking more generally, given a finite subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, is there a way of assigning a density value to each point $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ dependent on how many elements of $E$ are near $\vec{x}$?

My ideas:

1. I had the idea of assigning to each point on the map the number of people within, say, 10 miles of it, but that would both be a completely arbitrary decision and one that would lead to a discontinuous function.
2. The closest I have to a continuous function would be to assign to each $\vec{x}$ the point $f(\vec{x})=\Sigma_{\vec{y} \in E}\frac{1}{d(\vec{x},\vec{y})}$, with $d$ referring to the norm in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ This is (I think) a continuous (and differentiable) function everywhere in the compliment of $E$.

Finally, is it at all possible that the coastline paradox (or something like it) prevents any sort of objectively correct answer to this problem, in the sense that we could also assign each point the value of $\Sigma_{\vec{y} \in E}\frac{1}{d(\vec{x},\vec{y})^{2}}$ or $\Sigma_{\vec{y} \in E}\frac{1}{d(\vec{x},\vec{y})^{3}}$, and so on, and none would be objectively more correct than the others?

Comment: You need to define $d(\bar{x},\bar{y})$.  What is the point of such a map?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Sorry, $d(x,y)$ is meant to refer to the norm in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I'll edit it. The point would be to somehow remove the arbitrary factor of the borders of various regions and get a cleaner result.

Comment: E would need to be a function of x.  To be meaningful in San Francisco,  E would be a few square blocks, while in Wyoming county size E would suffice outside of its few cities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your idea sounds a bit like a convolution to me. You could construct a kernel of your choice, e.g. something like the squared exponential kernel:
$$
k(x, x') = \sigma^2 e^{-\frac{|x-x'|^2}{2l^2}}
$$
and sum it up $f(x) = \sum_{i} k(x,x_i)$ where $x_i$ is the position of each citizen.
Just make sure you normalize so that the integral of $f$ is correct, and pick the length scale depending on how much you want to smear out the results.

Your idea #1 wasn't smooth because you just didn't choose a smooth kernel.